# what are the causes for "checksum does not match inode" HD problem, even if it says the inode check passed?

Tags: fsck, inode, checksum

Root became RO after some minutes using the PC.
On reboot it required manual `fsck`.

Then this problem happened:
it said the inode check passed fine ok, but said this problem: "checksum does not match inode"
and I let it fix them all, and there were many like that.

But what I dont understand is how can a inode check pass ok, but the checksum may fail?
That error happened on the 2nd boot after installing kernel 5.13.0-27-generic (b4 that it was 5.11.0-38-generic).
Ubuntu 20.04.
Btw, this new kernel seems to manage RAM/Swap a huge lot better than previous one.

Comment: What does the syslog say (when the disk got mounted read-only)?

Comment: as I remember, after searching about it, when Root became RO it got unable to save anything they said. I wonder now, if logs were saved in another partition, it could help a lot!